# Google Maps Plugin - Ordering/grouping locations by address subfield

Tags: plugin-googlemaps

I have a Google Maps plugin `address` field and I'd like to show a tabular list of locations ordered by an address subfield like `address.country` or `address.city`.

And once I have that list I'd like to group those locations by an address subfield.

Something similar to this...

```
{% set allLocations = craft.entries.section('dealers').orderBy('address.city').all() %}
{% set allLocationsByCountry = allLocations|group(e => e.address.country) %}
```

Any suggestions for how to write the query and group filter?

Answer (score 1):

Author of the Google Maps plugin here, I'll do my best to answer this. Although I do suspect that it might be better handled by JavaScript on the front-end.

Let's break this into two separate parts...

#### Ordered by an Address subfield

I don't believe that it's possible to order by an Address subfield. The plugin is not changing the behavior of the `orderBy` parameter, and I don't believe there is a valid way to target an individual column.

```
{# This doesn't work #}
.orderBy('address.city')
```

Let me know if you find a way to do this, I'd love to be proven wrong.

#### Grouped by an Address subfield

Similarly, you could use the `groupBy` parameter, but I don't think that would work either.

```
{# This also doesn't work #}
.groupBy('address.country')
```

Again, let me know if you can find a syntax that works.

---

**As for an actual solution...** I'd recommend pulling down all of the Address data as-is, displaying it as a normal HTML table, and then use an off-the-shelf JS library to manipulate that data further.

There are many JS libraries that allow you to sort an HTML table, so I won't bother linking to one here. Your solution will likely rely on whatever JS libraries you are already using.

I know it's not exactly what you wanted to hear, but I hope that helps!